# Saxon EE (java) in a GraalVM native image

Tags: saxon

We are trying to use Saxon EE in our Quarkus application compiled down into a native image.

It looks like there is a lot of reflection going on in Saxon EE and we are fighting adding all these classes 1 by 1 into our reflection list.

We found this project https://github.com/murphye/saxon-graalvm-native-from-cpp/blob/main/saxon-lib/src/main/resources/reflection-config.json and taking their reflection list really helped us get closer, but there are still EE classes that we need to add to it.

Is there any reflection list out there for Saxon EE? Has anyone built a native version of Saxon EE that we can utilize?

Thank you,
-Jeff

Comment: I don't know what Quarkus is but as the link mentions cpp it might be an option to look into the Saxon-C EE or the recent SaxonC 11.1 EE release from Saxonica if C++ is the target. It doesn't use Graal, however, instead Excelsior Jet, to run with C/C++. Ignore the comment is you are just looking for a way to use Saxon Java EE with GraalVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve built a version using Saxon EE and Spring Native. I used the Native Agent to build the reflection list for me. You run this along with the JAR and ‘exercise’ the code paths by running your test suite through it or manual tests. Once you exit the files are created for you.

I was going to raise a question on the Saxonica support forums asking if there were plans to work with Spring and Qurakus to make this process smoother. Sounds like this might be in the works?

Comment: Yes we just now figured out how to do this an my college was able to get GraalVM to give us our reflection-config as well as our proxy-config and resource-config, this has gotten us just about there.

I have been in contact with the Saxonica guys and will provide our graal configs to them once we are done to give them a head start on their project to get a version of Saxon working with GraalVM

Answer (score 0):

Currently SaxonC is built by compiling the Java code of SaxonJ to native code using Excelsior JET. Having got the SaxonC 11.1 release out of the door earlier this week (and aware that Excelsior JET is no longer supported) our next plan is to look at rebuilding the product using GraalVM.

I think this is a fairly substantial undertaking, but it's hard to tell in advance. We do a fair bit of dynamic loading (which we had to get rid of in the conversion to SaxonCS), including the complex bits concerned with bytecode generation, but I don't think there's much reflection per se. Obviously you'll want to make sure bytecode generation is disabled, as well as reflexive extension functions. Most of the dynamic loading is concerned with loading user plug-ins named (as class names) in the configuration file or supplied as the values of configuration properties, and if you don't use these features, the loading shouldn't be a problem. There's also the JAXP service provider instantiation to contend with, my instinct is to strip all that out.

I would suggest trying to walk before you can run: make this work first on Saxon-HE, where you have access to the source code. If you can make progress on that then perhaps we can do some collaboration to extend it to the EE code. Please get in touch with us directly, this is off-topic for StackOverflow.

And thanks for the link to the Murphye project, which we weren't aware of.